# How to get WooCommerce formatted orders date localized in Spanish?

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, woocommerce, orders

I see the following code to display the completed date from WooCommerce orders

```
echo 'Fecha: '. $order->get_date_completed()->format ('j F, Y').'<br>';
```

But I would like the display to be formatted in Spanish. 
How can I get this date formatted in Spanish, like my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`WC_Datetime` `date_i18n() method`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_DateTime.html#_date_i18n) to display a localized formatted date like:

```
// Only for completed orders 
if( $date_completed = $order->get_date_completed() ){
    // Display the localized formatted date
    echo "Fecha: " . $date_completed->date_i18n('j F, Y') . "<br>";
}
```

It should work.

See also: [`date_i18n()` on WordPress Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/)